# How to use css variable in less file

Tags: css, reactjs, less, antd

I am using css variable in less file but it always return to me an error:

> Error evaluating function `fade`: Argument cannot be evaluated to a
> color

***.../custom-globals.less***

```
@import '~antd/es/style/themes/default.less';
@import '~antd/dist/antd.less';

@primary-color: var(--primary-color);
@link-color: #000000;
```

Error image:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHDA2.png)

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: I don't see a `fade` variable here. You'll have to inspect your application to figure out where that's coming from.

Comment: @Millhorn I saw this error message in terminal

Comment: Are you able to see which file that's coming from? Open the `default.less` and `antd.less` files and do a search for `fade` and see what's returned. That should get you started. There's not enough information in your question to provide a good answer.

Comment: A search of your error on Google brought me to this Github page... not sure if it helps, but it might point you in the right direction: https://github.com/ant-design/codemod-v4/issues/199

Comment: @Millhorn I updated error image in my question

Comment: I did help. I don't have access to your less files. I can't research this. You didn't provide enough information, but with that Github link, I think you should be on the right track. This will require you digging into your code base.